# Open GL ES more than one EAGLContext?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

I have two classes, let's call them parent and child, and both need to be rendered to the screen. The first one, the child, used to work fine. But then I decided that I needed to add a second class, the parent. First I moved the init code that creates the frame buffer and loads the textures from the child into the parent and then tried to call the draw method of the child class from the draw method of the parent class. Then the screen showed up black. I didn't understand what was going on so I tried with two contexts in each of the classes. That renders but the image doesn't move even though I'm drawing moving objects. For example, I have a square moving around and when you click on it it's supposed to change color but it doesn't anymore, even though the square class registers the tap.

Now my question: is it possible to have two classes, each with its own CADisplayLink? If yes, how would you implement the rendering? e.g. one vs. two EAGLContext's, etc.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the problem was that I rendered the buffer in the child class whereas I should've rendered it in the parent!
Cheers anyway!